# List index out of range error for python constant size list

Tags: python

I am trying to read a certain number of lines from a txt file and split store some of words per line into variables. However, I keep getting an index out of range error and I cannot understand why.

Here is the code:

```
for i in range(230218):
    count=i+1
    if count != coordinate:
            writefile.write(str(count)+"0")
    else:
            writefile.write(str(count)+coverage)
            lineread=f.readline()
            x=lineread.split()
            coordinate=int(x[1])
            coverage=x[3]
```

and the error say tat coordinate and coverage are the ones which are out of range.

edit: I think the problem was that the input file was too large so it wasn't generating a list for x at all. The problem resolved itself when I ran it on a different machine.

Comment: please [edit] your question and give the **full text** of the traceback

Comment: Not related to your question, but `230218` is a rather large number. You might want to use `xrange` in Python 2 for better performance and less memory use.

Comment: If you are using python < 3 you strongly should use `xrange`, it's an sequence object and it's evaluates lazily.Do you know that you can do `range(1, 230219)` this will avoid `count = i + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use `len(x)` maybe you get line without spaces so `split()` give you one element in `x` and `x[1]` doesn't exists.